# How to debug a "missing field `url`" error with the rocket_db_pools library

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I have a Postgres database running at the following url

```
postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/my_db
```

I am able to connect to it using pgAdmin and psql

```bash
psql postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/my_db
```

I have the following `Cargo.toml` file

```ini
[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.3", features = ["json"] }

[dependencies.rocket_db_pools]
version = "=0.1.0-rc.3"
features = ["sqlx_postgres"]

[default.databases.my_db_name]
url = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/my_db"
```

and this minimal rocket server

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

use rocket::serde::json::Json;
use rocket_db_pools::{sqlx, Connection, Database};

#[derive(Database)]
#[database("my_db_name")]
struct MyDB(sqlx::PgPool);

#[get("/test")]
async fn test(
    mut _db: Connection<MyDB>,
) -> Result<Json<()>, Json<()>> {
    Ok(Json(()))
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
        .mount("/", routes![test]) 
        .attach(MyDB::init())  
}
```

It feels like this exemple follows [the documentation](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket_db_pools/index.html#supported-drivers), but when running it I get the following

```
Error: failed to initialize database: bad configuration: missing field `url`
Error: Rocket failed to launch due to failing fairings:
   >> 'my_db' Database Pool
thread 'main' panicked at 'aborting due to fairing failure(s)', 
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

How can I know why isn't rocket_db_pools finding the URL field ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide the configuartion for rocket in a file called `Rocket.toml`, not in the `Cargo.toml` as the [docs state](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket_db_pools/index.html#configuration):

> By default, configuration can be provided in `Rocket.toml`

Comment: If you use workspaces: `Rocket.toml` must not be in the folder of the workspace member but in the root (next to `Cargo.lock`).